# How to dynamically call method in AWS-SDK using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm converting JS code to TypeScript (changed a bit to create a more [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the type variable is more complex, but the point is that it's a dynamic variable with the type `"transactGetItems" | "transactWriteItems"`).

```js
import {DynamoDB} from "aws-sdk";
const ddb = new DynamoDB();

let type: "transactGetItems" | "transactWriteItems" = Math.random() < .5 ? "transactGetItems" : "transactWriteItems";

const result = await ddb[type](transactionParams).promise();
return result.Responses ? await Promise.all(result.Responses.map((item, index: number) => {
    return processItem(item.Item);
})) : null;
```

I'm getting the following error tho:

> error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
>     Each member of the union type '{ (params: TransactGetItemsInput, callback?: (err: AWSError, data: TransactGetItemsOutput) => void): Request; (callback?: (err: AWSError, data: TransactGetItemsOutput) => void): Request<...>; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

[image]

Now if I do the following it works:

```js
const a = await aws.ddb()["transactWriteItems"](transactionParams).promise();
const b = await aws.ddb()["transactGetItems"](transactionParams).promise();
```

BUT, the entire reason I'm wanting to do it this way is because both the `transactGetItems` and `transactWriteItems` are incredibly similar in terms of the input and output.

This worked in JavaScript just fine.

Is there some trick to getting this to work correctly in TypeScript so that I can keep my code DRY and not repetitive? I know there are ways to do it that are more repetitive, but the entire goal here is to keep the code DRY and minimal.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it looks like the non working example is "transactGetItems" and the working example is "transactionGetItems"

Comment: @CharlesBamford Sorry. That was a mistake in writing the question. Just verified that my code is the correct `transactGetItems` throughout with the same error being thrown. So just a typo in the question, not the actual code. Edited the question to correct this.